# Use other characters as wildcard

Tags: qgis, expression

I am using QGIS-Version 3.8.3-Zanzibar

I want to use an expression to fill a new field with a string. For this I use a certain part of another field ("CAD-Layer")

The problem is that in this text are a lot of underscores used and if I now use my expression they are interpreted as wildcard for one character.
For example:

```
WHEN "CAD-layer" LIKE 'Bef_%_M_%' THEN 'Mauer'
WHEN "CAD-layer" LIKE 'Bef_%_S_%' THEN 'Schicht'
```

But if there is for example something like 'Bef_3013_S_umzMB' the result is 'Mauer' not 'Schicht'

Is there a possibility to use other characters than _ and % as wildcard?
Or is there another way to create an expression which brings the correct results?
The information in 'CAD-layer' is mainly the same style.
e.g.
ABC_1234_A_BC

Comment: You can run a replace on the string first, and modify your wildcard expression, or you can use a regex function instead.

Comment: is the length or the position of the char always the same? then you could work with strpos() and substr() functions.

Comment: I also thought about something like strpos() but sometimes it is not at the same position. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work with double backslash escape

```
case WHEN "CAD-layer" LIKE 'Bef\\_%\\_M\\_%' THEN 'Mauer'
WHEN "CAD-layer" LIKE 'Bef\\_%\\_S\\_%' THEN 'Schicht' end
```

I am not 100% sure one this one, because the doc mention single backslash escape only

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works!!!